# I've created a mat-table with paginator it works fine the only problem is some white spaces in between

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have created a mat-table with paginator all that works fine but I am having some unwanted space in between which makes the table look ugly. Is there any style I should change for that? Can I use some css styles or is there any predefined styles that I can use so that the style of the table is clean. It is for a project hence I would really appreciate it if you can explain to me clearly regarding the change that I should make to the given code.

Also my default theme is purple-green.

Also will any bootstrap classes work for this?

component.ts file

```
table mat-table class="table" matSort aria-label="Elements" [dataSource]="dataSource">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Pt_Id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Patient Id</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.Pt_Id}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Pt_Name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Patient Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.Pt_Name}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Pt_Age">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Patient Age</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.Pt_Age}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Department">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Department</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.Department}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Docname">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Doctor Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.Docname}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Pt_Email">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Patient Email</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.Pt_Email}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Pt_Mob">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Patient Mobile</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.Pt_Mob}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Options">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Options</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mr-1"
              data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"
              (click)="editClick(row)">
              Edit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mr-1"
              (click)="deleteClick(row)">
                  Delete</button>
      </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>

<mat-paginator [length]="1000" [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
</mat-paginator>
```

[Output of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK3M5.png)

Comment: Please can somebody help with this?

Comment: Maybe you should provide the css for your class `table`